# flutter - How to keep user signed-in with Google

Tags: dart, firebase-authentication, flutter, google-signin

I have used Google Sign In to authenticate users with Firebase Auth, and I successfully get back my Firebase User. I want to keep the user authenticated, when they come back to the app. How can I do the same?

Comment: I wrote a quick explanation of the flow below. If this somehow doesn't work for you, update your question to contain the [minimum complete code with which you can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you. I just didn't know the method. It works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Users already stay authenticated. After you restart the app, Firebase reads the credentials from disk, and refreshes the user's token. Since this requires a roundtrip to the server, it happens asynchronously. So be sure to `await _auth.currentUser()` to get notified of the user's status.

Whenever I'm wondering how to do such things, I look at the [FlutterFire sample app](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example/). This specific line can be found [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example/lib/signin_page.dart#L429).

Comment: it looks live developers have removed several packages from the plugins repository, along with FlutterFire at a certain commit. All those packages were great resources to refer the implementation.

Comment: The packages were moved to a new location: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to do the `auth.currentUser()` function in order to keep users authenticated and the best part is that this function will work even if the user is offline, which makes it very versatile.

Comment: i have this line but unfortunately, using the token in for example Google Drive APIs wont work.