# How to keep user logged Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an app in flutter and wanted the login to stay active even if the user closes the app.

What I wanted is that when the user closes the application it would open the "home" page.

This is my code:

```
class _SignFormState extends State<SignForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String email;
  String password;
  bool remember = false;
  final List<String> errors = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildEmailFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildPasswordFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          Row(
            children: [
              Spacer(),
            ],
          ),
          FormError(errors: errors),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
          DefaultButton(
            text: "Continuar",
            press: () async {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                _formKey.currentState.save();
                try {
                  UserCredential user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email,password: password);
                  KeyboardUtil.hideKeyboard(context);
                  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Tabs()),
                      (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                } catch (e) {
                  print("erro");}}},),],),);}

  TextFormField buildPasswordFormField() {}

  TextFormField buildEmailFormField() {}
}
```

Comment: Refer [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/) on how you can keep a firebase user logged in and check the auth state the next time the user logs in, the code in the example uses Java, but the same methods are available in the dart package for firebase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter - How to keep user signed-in with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773303/flutter-how-to-keep-user-signed-in-with-google)